# Peer chaincode install failed due to chaincode definition sequence mismatch

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Recently I have ran into a situation where I accidentally delete the /var/hyperledger/production folder. After rejoining the channel and finished  syncing from other peers, I got this error

```
+ peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg -o orderer0-orderer.orderer20:7050 --tls true --cafile /shared/crypto-config/orderer.orderer20/orderers/orderer0-orderer.orderer20/msp/tlsintermediatecerts/ica-orderer-orderer20-7054.pem --channelID htqachannel --name ht_cc --version b21734e0c25e509e3ff4b3dc96b78ca83047aa9e --package-id ht_cc_b21734e0c25e509e3ff4b3dc96b78ca83047aa9e:76c6642ba927c690ad5a402d22f3ec28c581ef76cea8828b9af583a5021bea23 --sequence 1 --waitForEvent
+ res=1
+ set +x
Error: proposal failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'ApproveChaincodeDefinitionForMyOrg': currently defined sequence 109 is larger than requested sequence 1
```

Are there anyway to make the chaincode definition sequence on this peer to match the current defined sequence ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment the chaincode sequence number when upgrading chaincode definition. From the error it seems your current definition is having a sequence number 109. So you have to provide 110 as sequence instead of 1.